# AJAX error with response 200 (custom data type)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a custom dataType.
My ajax request has these parameters:

```
accepts: {
    'jsonc': 'application/x-jsonc'
},
converters: {
    'jsonc': function(string) {
        console.log(1);
        return JSON.parse(string);
    }
},
dataType: "jsonc",
```

From the request, this is the content type being sent: "Content-Type:application/x-jsonc"

But instead of running the custom jsonc converter function, it goes straight to error with response code 200 - I know that because console is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: response 200 is usually success response..

Comment: what are you trying to connect to? can you share some more code?

Comment: What is purpose of `application/x-jsonc`? Is response `JSON`? Does server response header contain `Content-Type:application/x-jsonc`?

Comment: @JanR Im connecting to my localhost, cross domain (but all headers are sent). My "response" is '{"status": true}'. If I remove "dataType: 'jsonc'" it does parse to JSON, but never goes through my converter.

Comment: @guest271314 this is sample code. I created an about 50% compression to JSON, because im sending about 50MB of data, and it takes time.

Comment: try: `   'text jsonc': function(string) {
        console.log(1);
        return JSON.parse(string);
    }`

Comment: @NishanthMatha That partially works. it now uses the converter (console is logged), but does not go to my success function (which contains only console.log(2))

Comment: can you edit your post to show entire ajax call?

Comment: @NishanthMatha Nevermind, it acctually works now! needed a small change to my function, im not sure what yet, but now it goes to the converter and then to the success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jQuery Documentation:

> `converters` (default: {"* text": window.String, "text html": true, "text json": jQuery.parseJSON, "text xml": jQuery.parseXML})
>   Type: PlainObject
>   An object containing dataType-to-dataType converters. Each converter's value is a function that returns the transformed value of the response

It looks like `converter` object expect a prefix `text` in the property. So,

try:

```
 'text jsonc': function(string) { console.log(1); 
               return JSON.parse(string); }
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/